# Display ambient video for Desktop but replace it with image for mobile

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm building a WordPress theme where the hero has an ambient video playing in the background. Currently, the video is of type `file`.

**Code so far:**

```html
<?php

'video_mp4'    => get_field('hero_video_mp4')
'video_poster' => get_field('hero_video_poster'),

      // Building the  Shortcode
      $teaserAttr =  array(
      'mp4'      => $video_mp4,
      'poster'   => $video_poster,
      'preload'  => 'auto',
      'autoplay' => 'on',
      'loop'     => 'on',
      'muted'    => true,
      'class'    => 'hero-video-loop'
      );

?>


    <div class="hero__container--teaser">
        <div class="hero__teaser">
          <?php echo wp_video_shortcode(  $teaserAttr );  ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, on screen width 768px, I want to remove the video and replace it with an image. Essentially replace `$video_mp4` with `$video_poster`. Since PHP is server side, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if (screen.width >= 768) {
    <?= wp_video_shortcode($teaserAttr); ?>
} else {
   ...
}

</script>
```